# Issue with positioning the footer text and footer rule

Tags: header-footer, positioning

Consider this MWE, why is the footer rule position different on page 1 compared to the rest of the pages? Also related to the footer, how can I move the footer text down without affecting the position of the rule or the rest of the objects on the page.

**Overall page layout**

[image]

**Page 1**

Notice the position of the rule in relation the grey rectangle and the example-image.

[image]

**Page 2**

[image]

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=3.5cm,bottom=3.2cm,footskip=1.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Dummy text

% TIKZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

% CUSTOM HEADERS AND FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{\today}
\lhead{}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{SOME TEXT GOES HERE}
\rfoot{mywebsite.com
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [inner sep=0cm,outer sep=0,yshift=1.75cm,xshift=8.75cm] (picture)
      at (current page.south){\includegraphics[height=1.5cm,width=1.5cm]{example-image-a}};
\fill [gray,opacity=0.1] ($ (picture) + (-0.75,0.75+0.2) $) rectangle ($ (picture) + (0.75,0.75+0.2+29.7-2-1.5-0.2) $)  % 29.7cm-2cm-1.5cm-0.2cm
    node [text opacity=0.5 , text=black ,  rotate=-90, yshift=-0.75cm, xshift=1.8cm] {\Huge Testing};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MWE produces a warning about the `\headheight` being too small. It notes that it will change this but then page layouts might be inconsistent (or words to that effect).

Before `\begin{document}` Put

```
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
```

which makes your MWE pages consistent.

It's always useful to check for any warning messages --- GOM.